# How to edit object deformed by a curve modifier

Tags: modeling

In the objects that are deforming along a curve, I would like to know how to move an edge along the curve.

When I try to edit an object that is deformed along a curve in the "Edit Mode", the object reverts to its original form. I want to edit in a state of being deformed, before applying the modifier.
And if possible, I want to move some edges along the curve that are used for deformation. Sorry for my poor English.

[image]

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean are you trying to move the red edges along the pipe?  If so you are looking to *Edge Slide* them by pressing [G] twice in a row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the modifier there are two options that will allow you to work in edit mode.

[image]

The first one will allow you to display the modifier in edit mode.

The second will allow you to edit the mesh while is being deformed by the modifier:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! My problem about editing of deformation was almost solved. Thanks again! ;-)